# Efficient queries for relationships in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, optimization, sqlalchemy

A little background: I am creating a web application (using Flask) for use internally in an organization. The webapp will have a very simple message board that allows users to post and comment on posts.

I'm doing this for a couple reasons -- mainly to get experience with Flask and to better understand sqlalchemy.

This is the database schema with some non-important info removed:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    # information about user
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref = 'author', lazy = 'dynamic')
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref = 'author', lazy = 'dynamic')

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    # information about posts (title, body, timestamp, etc.)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref = 'thread', lazy = 'dynamic')

class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    # information about comment (body, timestamp, etc)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))   # author
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))   # thread
```

When I render the messages view, I want to  be able to display a table of threads with the following information for each message:

- Title
- Author
- # Replies
- Time of last modification

Right now, my query to get the messages looks like this:

```
messages = Post.query.filter_by(post_type = TYPE_MESSAGE).order_by('timestamp desc')
```

With that query, I get easily get the title and author for each post. However, it currently orders by the date the message was created (I know that is wrong, and I know why) and I can't easily get the number of replies.

If I was looping through the messages to render them in the application, I **could** access the `message.comments` attribute and use that to find the length and get the timestamp of the most recent comment, but am I correct in assuming that to get that data it would require another database query (to access `message.comments`)?

Since that is the case, I could get the list of all of the messages with one query (good) but if I had `n` messages, it would require `n` additional database queries to populate the messages view with the information that I want, which is far from efficient.

This brings me to my main question: is it possible to use aggregate operators with SQLAlchemy as you would in a regular SQL query to get `COUNT(comments)` and `MAX(timestamp)` in the original query for `messages`? Or, is there another solution to this that I haven't explored yet? Ideally, I want to be able to do this all in one query. I looked through the SQLAlchemy documentation and couldn't find anything like this. Thanks!

Comment: I believe most forum software solves this problem by storing those two values at the `Post` level. It removes the need for a join for information that is displayed frequently, especially when you're retrieving multiple posts.

Comment: That makes sense. From what you're saying, it seems like I would have to add an attribute to `Post` called replies and increment it every time a comment is added. Would `Post` then have to have something like an `add_comment(c)` function (not necessarily good design -- what happens when a comment is deleted?) or is there another way to do that via SQLAlchemy whenever a comment is added to the db that references a certain `Post`?

Comment: Personally I'd do it with triggers in the database. If you want to keep things in the ORM, [Flask-SQLAlchemy has support for a couple of signals](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/signals.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I don't know why I didn't think about triggers. Do you have any experience using them with SQLAlchemy? Adding two triggers for each comment (to update replies and last modified) would make insertions a little bit slower for comments but it should be faster than doing all those queries to populate the messages view. Also, I'm using version 0.7.9. Is there similar support for older versions?

Comment: If you go with the database triggers, SQLAlchemy doesn't have to do anything (except maybe execute the `CREATE TRIGGER` statements if you want it to). If you want to use the signals that are in SQLAlchemy, those have been around for a while. They're certainly in 0.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

For counting, you can try this (an example):

```
session.query(Comment).join(Post).filter_by(id=5).count()
```

or

```
sess.query(Comment).join(Post).filter(Post.id==5).count()
```

And, yes you can use aggregates:

```
sess.query(func.max(Comment.id)).join(Post).filter_by(id=5).all()
```

or

```
sess.query(func.max(Comment.id)).join(Post).filter(Post.id==5).all()
```